# JAX-WS CXF empty XOP multipart attachments with file size > ~210kb

Tags: java, apache, cxf, jax-ws, xop

I am using jax-ws cxf to load documents from a SOAP interface. I can get the correct document via SoapUI (xop/multipart). Unfortunately, when I try to load the attachment via code, the `CachedOutputStream` is empty for files greater than ~210kb.

**What I tried**:

- Activate MTOMFeature for my WebServiceClient
- Play with JVM arguments `CachedOutputStream.Threshold` and `CachedOutputStream.MaxSize`
- Use different versions of apache-cxf (`3.2.1` or `3.1.14`)

**When debugging**:

`PhaseInterceptorChain#doIntercept` uses the `AttachmentInInterceptor` (at `currentInterceptor.handleMessage(message);`) which loads the attachments with `LazyAttachmentCollection` and adds it to the message.

1. happy case: document is loaded into CachedOutputStream and available after the for-loop.
2. error case (file too big?): document is available directly after currentInterceptor.handleMessage is called, but disappears when the loop has finished

   In both of the above cases however, a correct tmp file is saved to my disk (with exactly my document's content). Furthermore, I can load that file in both cases even when the loop has finished with: `((org.apache.cxf.attachment.LazyAttachmentCollection)(message.getAttachments())).loadAll();`

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this ? I'm currently stuck with the same problem. Small attachments work fine, larger ones are just missing from the request, although cid is generated and placed inline.

Comment: Using jax-ws metro instead of cxf would solve the issue. But I have to use cxf .. so I'm still stuck with the problem. Unfortunately, I did not have time to create a standalone app to prove the issue for a proper bug report.

Comment: I found a workaround for something similar lately.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51216192/spring-boot-apache-cxf-3-2-5-with-mtom-sends-empty-attachment/51327860#51327860

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with apache-cxf 3.1.6. The issue was that files above 102kB were empty. After some digging it turned turned out to be "attachment-memory-threshold" which u can set in requestContext, for some reason file cache doesnt seem to work.